# Why is result from STANDARD_HASH('expr', 'MD5') always in uppercase?

Tags: oracle, encryption, hash, md5, oracle12c

I need get `MD5` hash in oracle, for this I use `STANDARD_HASH` function, but I have little misunderstanding.

In oracle: `select  STANDARD_HASH('word', 'MD5') from dual` result is:

`C47D187067C6CF953245F128B5FDE62A`

alphabetical characters are in uppercase.

But in other database, for example in mysql, result from: `select md5('word')` is:

`c47d187067c6cf953245f128b5fde62a`

exactly same result (lowercase) is from for example php's `md5()` function.

Question: Why returns oracle's STANDARD_HASH('expr', 'MD5')   alphabetical characters in upper case? something is wrong here?

Comment: Neither is right or wrong, it's just that one vendor chose uppercase another vendor chose lowercase for hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Oracle's finally created a simple hashing function, woohoo! Unfortunately, that does mean I'm going to have to re-write the lot _again_ :-(. I have no idea why they deprecate so mush of this functionality every time...

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a standardized case (uppercase or lowercase) for hexadecimal encoding. According to [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-8) the encoding should be in uppercase. But there are other standards out there that use lower case.

Hash functions are defined to output bytes, without specifying any hexadecimal encoding. So if you want to compare hexadecimal strings instead of bytes which, in my opinion, is the preferred method to compare hashes, then you need to do a case insensitive compare. Comparing bytes should however be preferred.

Personally I prefer uppercase (as I think it is easier to read (people read mostly the top of letters) and because there is at least a specific standard for it. But others use lowercase, and there are arguments for that as well.

As for why Oracle returns uppercase for that specific function: that's a question that only Oracle can answer I'm afraid. "Because that's how it is defined" is the only thing we can come up with.